# General topology exercise (equivalent condition for simple connectivity)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a pathwise-connected topological space. Prove that $X$ is simply connected iff every continuous $f:S^1\to X$ can be extended to a continuous function $g:D^2\to X$.

How can I use the fact that there is an identification mapping between $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $D^2$ which collapses three of the four sides to a point?

Thank you

Comment: You could prove this also directly. If $X$ is simply connected then every path is homotopic to a constant. This is sufficient for a prove.

Comment: A homotopy of between two pathes is a map $I\times I\to X$. Can you see why a homotopy between a loop and a constant loop which leaves the basepoint fixed factors through the identification map you described?